# android ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent)

Tags: android, android-activity

i designed a simple application in android but when i run it over emulator it shows application stopped...i tried to find solution and came across using breakpoints...but when i put breakpoints and debug the application it shows "source not found" in ddms perspective

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent).
```

can anybody out here suggest what i do now...

this is what my log looks like

```
02-20 04:28:21.232: D/AndroidRuntime(607): Shutting down VM
02-20 04:28:21.232: W/dalvikvm(607): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apps/com.example.apps.Act}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at com.example.apps.Act.onCreate(Act.java:16)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-20 04:28:21.262: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  ... 11 more
02-20 04:28:31.283: I/Process(607): Sending signal. PID: 607 SIG: 9
```

Activity class

```
package com.example.apps; 

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 

public class Act extends Activity { 

    Rest r=new Rest(); 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save); 
   save.setOnClickListener(onSave); 
} 

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() { 

     public void onClick(View v) { 
         EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name); 
         EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);  
         r.setName(name.getText().toString());
         r.setAddress(address.getText().toString()); 
     }  
}; 

}
```

Comment: What is at line 16 of `Act`? Show `onCreate()`Something is null

Comment: save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

Comment: Please edit your subject so that it's an actual meaningful question, so that it is useful in a search by future readers (and so that it contains some idea of what your question is about, which in this case is the runtime error you're getting). Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite:thank u for suggestion,i will keep it in mind always...

Comment: What is onSave and save, button I'm hoping? Can you edit your question with that section of code, the `onCreate()`?

Comment: @codeMagic my act.java is as below

Comment: "my act.java is as below " below what?

Comment: package com.example.apps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Act extends Activity {

Comment: Rest r=new Rest();
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
 Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
 save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
 }

Comment: @KaranMer - Edit your question and add the source code there. It's frustratingly hard to read in comments.

Comment: private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
 EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
 EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
 r.setName(name.getText().toString());
 r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
 }
 };
}

Comment: @dymmeh:yes trying to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easy, let's change your `onClick()` like

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // do stuff here
}
});
```

Where `save` is your button. From now on, edit your question with the updated code so its easier to read. I was having trouble reading your code in the comment but it looks like if you change it like this it should work for you. **[Here is a good discussion about the different ways to use `onClick()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082344/how-to-handle-a-button-being-clicked-in-android)**

I was going to delete but this information may help others. However, as pointed out by @dymmeh `setContentView()` isn't called so there is no layout to get your button from. This needs to be called with the appropriate layout, `R.layout.your_layout` before you can reference any views, `Buttons`, `EditText`, etc...

Comment: This won't fix anything. If you notice he isn't even setting a content view so the save button will always be null. Free answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and no I didn't notice. It's incredibly hard to make out code in comments, especially a whole method. Good catch!

Comment: @dymmeh thanks :) I would gladly delete and let you post.

Comment: @codeMagic:i did setContentView(R.layout.activity_Act); but it still shows "activity_act cannot be resolved"

Comment: it went away i just did setContentView(R.layout.activity_);

Comment: thnx a lot @codeMagic

Comment: layout files should be lower case separated with underscores activity_layout for example