# If Loop won't execute after closing dialog (first time using java) Java/Android

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm trying to change a the text in a textview after this dialog box is closed by pressing the "ok_button". But I wanted to do it in a loop. I set "alleroclosed" as boolean and initialized it as false. After I press the "ok_button" the loop will not initiate, or it won't take my boolean variable "alleroclosed"

```
{ 
     Button ok_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Ok_button);
     ok_button.setOnClickListener(
         new OnClickListener() 
         {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                 alleroclosed=true;
                 dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });

     if(alleroclosed) 
     {
         alleroclosed=false;
         alleroSTATUS.setText("it works");
     }
}
```

========
It won't change the string to "it works"

If you can help me in any way I'd really appreciate it. I'm a true novice at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is that you are calling

```
if (alleroclosed) {
  alleroclosed=false;
  alleroSTATUS.setText("it works");
}
```

outside of `onClick()` method and for this reason it never be applied.

Your block of code is directly placed in onCreate() method and this method is not called when click event is catched so it is applied only once - when onCreate() is called with alleroclosed = false.

So it will work when you'll place it inside of `onClick()` method.

```
...
public void onClick(View v) {
   alleroclosed = true;
   dialog.dismiss();
   if (alleroclosed) {
      alleroclosed=false;
      alleroSTATUS.setText("it works");
   }
...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The boolean will be set to true only when the OK button is clicked. The `if` block is executed right after you've created and registered the listener.

The content of the if vlock should be in the `onClick()` method of the listener if you want this code to be executed when the OK button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

the task which you want to perform on button click should be written in onClick() method...
in the above code you want to call if after dialog closes when you click on your button...
so simply make your onclick() as below

```
public void onClick(View v) {
dialog.dismiss();
if (somecondition) {
  // task you want to do...
}
}
```

the following link discuss the ways to use onClick()
[How to handle a button being clicked in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082344/how-to-handle-a-button-being-clicked-in-android)
hope it works...